# How to limit number of characters in TextFormField?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way in **dart language** to keep the maximum input length fixed in `TextFormField`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use `inputFormatters` property. The following code would limit the textFormField to 42 in length :

```
new TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(42),
  ],
);
```

**UPDATE:** Import the package first. `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: It's not working. Shows undefined class error in `LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter` line

Comment: The class has been in the framework for 4 months [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c02b6a8bcf174e5220259f839705afeace151e92/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart#L133) . If it doesn't works for you, try upgrading your flutter version.

Comment: You may also simply need `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: is there any difference between LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(length) and maxlength ? Other than the counter? which of course can be shrunk by using counter: SizedBox.shrink().

Answer (score 29):

use `maxLength`

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _deskripsiController,
  onFieldSubmitted: (String value){
        setState(() {
          _deskripsiController.text = value;
        });
  },
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: "Deskripsi",
  ),
  maxLength: 8,
)
```

Comment: LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter doesnt work. maxLength is the correct answer.

Comment: This is nicer than LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter because it shows also the progressive chars on the UI out of the box

Answer (score 6):

best way is inputFormatters option:

```
inputFormatters: [
   new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),// for mobile 
],
```

Comment: LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(9), works with flutter 3.0.5 after run it on mobile and macos emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to hahnsaja answer after you add maxLength - counter appears at the bottom of the TextFormField widget. To be able to hide it, add this to InputDecoration :

```
counterText: '',
counterStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
```

Example:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _deskripsiController,
  onFieldSubmitted: (String value){
        setState(() {
          _deskripsiController.text = value;
        });
  },
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: "Deskripsi",
        counterText: '',
        counterStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
  ),
  maxLength: 8,
)
```

Comment: Just setting the counterText to an empty string works - you don't need to set the fontSize to 0.

Answer (score 0):

try with the below code, here is one TextFormField where I'm taking a mobile number with max 10 digits

```
TextFormField(inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)]) 
// replace your max length instead of 10
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.